# How to use functions that can throw errors in SwiftUI views?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a utiltiy function that saves data to `CoreData`.

```swift
func saveData(content: String) throws -> Void {
    // saves a model to CoreData
}
```

I want to fire this function when a `Button` is tapped by a user. Something like

```swift
Button(action: saveData)
```

But when I attempt this I get an error `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '() -> Void'`.

Is it possible to do what I am imagining or is there some other best practice I should be doing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621431/catching-errors-in-swiftui

Comment: Oh nice. So it seems like I need to toggle some Boolean value to catch it outside then do something else, is that right?

Comment: That was the solution presented in that post. Mostly I was just trying to suggest how to call the throwing function. But yeah, I guess you have to figure out what to do if the save fails :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you @MikeTaverne looks promising. I'll try it out

Comment: For posterity, you cannot throw directly from within the `Button` view or any view but instead you have to catch and toggle a boolean than fire off an `.alert` as a view modifier. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:message:)-8584l

Comment: if you `throw` you need to use `do try catch` to handle the error

Answer (score 1):

```
@State private var showError = false

Button(action: {
do {
try saveData()
} catch {
showError = true
}
}, label: { 
...
})
```

Then show the error with the .alert modifier